# Weird output using html tables

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
require_once('../phpFunctions/funciones.php');
conectar('localhost', 'root', '*******', 'tutoriales');

echo "<table cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\">";
for ($x = 0; $x <= 9; $x++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 9; $y++) {
        $numero = $x."".$y;   
        $region = (int)$numero;
        $sentencia = @mysql_query('select type,region from tutorial1_estrellas where region='.$region.'');
        $lanzar = @mysql_fetch_object($sentencia);
        if($lanzar[1]==$region){
            switch ($lanzar[0]) {
            case "red":
            echo "<td><img src=\"../images/redRegion.png\"></td>";   
            break;
            case "yellow":
            echo "<td><img src=\"../images/yellowRegion.png\"></td>";   
            break;
            case "blue":
            echo "<td><img src=\"../images/blueRegion.png\"></td>";   
            break;
        }
    } else  
        echo "<td><img src=\"../images/voidRegion.png\"></td>";   
    }   
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

The HTML output looks like a huge ECHO but not a normal table, is this an error or this is normal output in php? I'm new to PHP so please bear with me.

OUTPUT:

`"; for ($x = 0; $x "; for ($y = 0; $y if($lanzar[1]==$region){ switch ($lanzar[0]) { case "red": echo ""; break; case "yellow": echo ""; break; case "blue": echo ""; break; } }else echo ""; } echo ""; } echo ""; ?>`

The loop makes a 10x10 table where the images of each cell are defined by the result of the SQL query in the switch.

Comment: what is conectar() ?? Is this a php file ? or a html file ?

Comment: Enter code in proper format .

Comment: @swapnesh Probably connection to db.

Comment: conectar() is a function created by the OP to connect to the required localhost/root or is what I believe. Es así @user1746758?

Comment: @PLB yeah very first impression but i just want to make sure if he is refering to this conectar() or mysql_connect() ?

Comment: If PHP code gets printed to the client, the script must have been closed right before; but there is no closing PHP tag visible right before the loop. Check for it in your original code to make sure it was not just a copy-paste error that stripped that one out. Also, if you use single quotes to enclose strings, you don't need to escape all the double quotes inside it: e.g. `echo '<table cellspacing="0" border="1" cellpadding="0">';`

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your server is properly set to run PHP instead of displaying it. From the output it looks like your problem is that your web server doesn't run PHP code so your browser tries to display your PHP code as HTML.

Create a PHP file (i.e.: test.php) and put the following into it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then try to get this file. If the output is not a table with PHP settings, then something is wrong with your web server setup.

Comment: This looks like the problem. I stripped all the code except the table tags and it produced the 10 X 10 matrix. The stripped out code looks valid